# How to write map collection on file and read it?

Tags: java, file, collections, iostream

I want to make collection with file paths and statue of each file then save it in file
and read it again when i need to that in java and what best collection type to this.
type of status boolian lock or unlock

Comment: What kind of status you want to store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the status is a boolean the following would work:

```
Map<File,Boolean> status = new HashMap<File,Boolean>();
```

Since [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html), [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) and [`Boolean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html) all implement [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) you can write the map to a file using an [`ObjectOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) and read it back with an [`ObjectInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html):

```
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("status.dat");
  ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
  oos.writeObject(status);
  oos.close();
```

If the status becomes more complex then be sure use a class that implements `Serializable` or if it's a custom class implement `Serializable` yourself.

Comment: status boolian type its lock or not lock

Answer (score 3):

Use the Properties object, as you can use the string based save and load.

Comment: This is good because unlike Serializing a Map, the output file is human-readable. Properties also offers good facilities to read/write boolean values. +1

Comment: If the os is windows and absolute paths should be stored the ":" after the drive letter must be escaped